# no data when loading json in pyhon

Tags: python, json, loading

I'm just want to print the json file like that

```
import json   
from country_codes import get_country_code

filename = 'gdp.json'

with open(filename) as f:
    pop_data = json.load(f)

cc_populations = {}

for pop_dict in pop_data:
    if pop_dict['Year'] == '1970':
        country_name = pop_dict['Country Name']
        population = int(float(pop_dict['Value']))
        code = get_country_code(country_name)
        if code:
            print(code + ": " + str(population))
        else:
            print('ERROR - ' + country_name)
```

json file is [here](https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/gdp/gdp_json/data/1a2503aa36368933be8f9a96e1dc16de/gdp_json.json)

when it runs, nothing comes up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The years in your JSON are integers.

change `if pop_dict['Year'] == '1970':` to `if pop_dict['Year'] == 1970:`

Working Example:

```
pop_data = [{"Country Code": "ARB", "Country Name": "Arab World", "Value": 25760683041.0857, "Year": 1968},{"Country Code": "ARB", "Country Name": "Arab World", "Value": 28434203615.4829, "Year": 1969},{"Country Code": "ARB", "Country Name": "Arab World", "Value": 31385499664.0672, "Year": 1970},]

import json

cc_populations = {}
for pop_dict in pop_data:
    if pop_dict['Year'] == 1970:
        country_name = pop_dict['Country Name']
        population = int(float(pop_dict['Value']))
        code = (country_name)
        if code:
            print(code + ": " + str(population))
        else:
            print('ERROR - ' + country_name)
```

Output:

> Arab World: 31385499664

Side note: `Value` is already a float, thus casting `float(pop_dict['Value'])` is not necessary.